# Function only mapped over the first image of the collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, vegetation-index

If anyone could help with this please. 
I need to map a function over an image collection. The problem is that the function is applied only on the first image of the collection and not on the rest. Here is the code for it.

```
A = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD09GA"),
    ocean = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYDOCGA"),
    geometry1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([10.644168108701706, 64.4188479841206]);

var b1 = A.select('sur_refl_b01')
var oceanb11 = ocean.select('sur_refl_b11')

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

var innerjoin = ee.Join.inner();

// Inner join applied. The output is an imagecollection.
var innerjoinedMODIS = innerjoin.apply(b1, oceanb11, filter)

var joinedMODIS = innerjoinedMODIS.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})
//print (joinedMODIS)

var dated = joinedMODIS.filterDate('2002-07-05', '2003-07-01')
print(dated,null,'dated')

//PRI for single image
var single = ee.Image (dated.first())
//print (single)


var addPRI = function(image) {
  var pri = single.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b11', 'sur_refl_b01']).rename('PRI');
  return single.addBands(pri);
};

//Test the addPRI function on a single image.
var testpri = addPRI(single).select('PRI');
//print (testpri)
//Map.addLayer(testpri,null,'testpri singleimage')

// pri for dated collection
var datedPRI = dated.map(addPRI)
print(datedPRI,null,'datedpri')
print(ui.Chart.image.series(datedPRI, geometry1, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000))
```

Comment: Hi Kadir, Thanks for editing, but still the result is function being mapped on only one image. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. I want the function to be mapped on each image in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addPRI = function(image) {
  var pri = single.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b11', 'sur_refl_b01']).rename('PRI');
  return single.addBands(pri);
};
```

In this mapping function you are using the previously-declared `single` image rather than the variable holding the mapped image `image`. Change `single.addBands(pri)` to `image.addBands(pri)` and it will work as a map should.

Comment: Hi Kevin, image.addBands (pri) generates an error " image.addBands is not a function "

Comment: @MKM Then you probably need a cast there same as you needed for `single`, so I should have written `ee.Image(image).addBands(pri)`.

Comment: Thanks alot Kevin! :-) it worked :-)